# Trying to compile C++ code and getting error LNK1104 cannot open file ifwin.lib

Tags: c++, linker, lnk

My problem is "Error LNK1104: cannot open file "ifwin.lib" " 
I've tried going to the properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies and adding it that way. I've tried properties -> Linker-> input-> Ignore specific default libraries and that didn't work. I looked online to where I could download the library. So I am coming to "you" with my problem hoping for a little guidance.

Comment: cannot open file seems like a permissions issue to me.

Comment: I am fairly certain I have all the required permissions.

Comment: can we see your code and what u are typing into the command line please?

Comment: " I looked online to where I could download the library". So the lib does not exist on your machine? A quick search shows this is a part of the intel fortran library.

Comment: See I saw that when I was searching but I don't know how to find that library on my machine.

Comment: @user2023068 you might not have it or need to download/install it somehow.